# Unable to Bind a Text Entry that's a IsVisible and BindingContext to a Switch

Tags: xaml, xamarin.forms, data-binding

I'm using MVVM architecture to build my app.
On the registration screen, I am able to bind all Text Entries if I don't use the IsVisible and BindingContext properties that are tied to the switch.

I tested all fields they work ok. But if I add:

IsVisible="{Binding IsToggled}" BindingContext="{x:Reference IsProviderSwitch}"

in the stacklayout opening tag all the entries that are below the switch don't send the entries to create the Proveedor object, thus, getting an error.

This is the code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="miturnoya.Views.RegistrationPage">

    <StackLayout VerticalOptions="Center"
                 Margin="20">

        <Label Text="Formulario de Registro"
               FontSize="Large"
               TextColor="Black"
               HorizontalOptions="Center"
               Margin="5"/>

        <Entry x:Name="contactNameEntry"
                Text="{Binding ContactName}"
                Placeholder="Nombre"
                Keyboard="Text"/>

        <Entry x:Name="celularNumberEntry"
                Text="{Binding CelularNumber}"
                Placeholder="Número Celular"
                Keyboard="Telephone"/>

        <Entry x:Name="celularCompanyEntry"
                Text="{Binding CelularCompany}"
                Placeholder="Empresa Celular"
                Keyboard="Text"/>

        <Entry x:Name="emailEntry"
               Text="{Binding Email}"
               Placeholder="Email"
               Keyboard="Email"/>

        <Entry x:Name="passwordEntry"
               Text="{Binding Password}"
               Placeholder="Contraseña"
               IsPassword="True"/>

        <Entry x:Name="confirmPasswordEntry"
               Text="{Binding ConfirmPassword}"
               Placeholder="Confirmar Contraseña"
               IsPassword="True"/>

        <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal" Spacing="10">

            <Label Text="Es Proveedor?"/>
            <Label Text="No/Si"/>

            <Switch x:Name="IsProviderSwitch" 
                   HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand"
                   OnColor="DeepSkyBlue"
                   IsToggled="{Binding IsProvider}"
                   ThumbColor="{StaticResource MainButtonColor}"/>

        </StackLayout>

        


        <StackLayout IsVisible="{Binding IsToggled}" BindingContext="{x:Reference IsProviderSwitch}">

            <Entry 
               x:Name="idProveedor"
               Text="{Binding IdProveedor}"
               Placeholder="Id Proveedor"
               Keyboard="Text"/>

            <Entry 
               x:Name="providerCompanyEntry"
               Text="{Binding RazonSocial}"
               Placeholder="Razon Social"
               Keyboard="Text"/>

            <Entry 
               x:Name="cuitEntry"
               Text="{Binding Cuit}"
               Placeholder="CUIT"
               Keyboard="Numeric"/>

            <Entry 
               x:Name="domicilioFiscalEntry"
               Text="{Binding DomicilioFiscal}"
               Placeholder="Domicilio Fiscal"
               Keyboard="Text"/>

        </StackLayout>




        <Button
            x:Name="RegistrationButton"
                Command="{Binding RegisterCommand}"
                Text="Registrarse"
                BackgroundColor="{StaticResource MainButtonColor}"
                TextColor="White"
                Margin="60,20,60,20"/>




    </StackLayout>

</ContentPage>
```

ViewModel file

```
public class RegistrationPageViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        IUserService _userService;

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        public void OnPropertyChanged(string name)
        {
            PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;
            if (handler != null)
                handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(name));
        }

        public RegistrationPageViewModel(IUserService userService)
        {

            _userService = userService;

        }

        private List<Usuario> usuariosList;

        public List<Usuario> UsuariosList
        {
            get { return usuariosList; }
            set
            {
                usuariosList = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("UsuariosList");

            }
        }

        private string contactName;

        public string ContactName
        {
            get { return contactName; }
            set
            {
                contactName = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("ContactName");

            }
        }

        private string celularNumber;

        public string CelularNumber
        {
            get { return celularNumber; }
            set
            {
        celularNumber = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("CelularNumber");

            }
        }

        private string celularCompany;

        public string CelularCompany
        {
            get { return celularCompany; }
            set
            {
        celularCompany = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("CelularCompany");

            }
        }

        private string email;

        public string Email
        {
            get { return email; }
            set
            {
                email = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("Email");
            }

        }

        private string password;

        public string Password
        {
            get { return password; }
            set
            {
                password = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("Password");
            }
        }

        private string confirmPassword;

        public string ConfirmPassword
        {
            get { return confirmPassword; }
            set
            {
                confirmPassword = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("ConfirmPassword");
            }
        }

        private bool isProvider;

        public bool IsProvider
        {
            get { return isProvider; }
            set
            {
                isProvider = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("IsProvider");
            }
        }

        private string userType;

        public string UserType
        {
            get { return userType; }
            set
            {
                userType = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("UserType");

            }
        }

        private long idProveedor;

        public long IdProveedor
        {
            get { return idProveedor; }
            set
            {
                idProveedor = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("IdProveedor");

            }
        }

        private string razonSocial;

        public string RazonSocial
        {
            get { return razonSocial; }
            set
            {
                razonSocial = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("RazonSocial");

            }
        }

        private string cuit;

        public string Cuit
        {
            get { return cuit; }
            set
            {
                cuit = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("Cuit");

            }
        }


        private string domicilioFiscal;

        public string DomicilioFiscal
        {
            get { return domicilioFiscal; }
            set
            {
                domicilioFiscal = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("DomicilioFiscal");

            }
        }

        


        public Command RegisterCommand
        {
            get
            {
                return new Command(() =>
                {
                    if (Password == ConfirmPassword)
                        RegisterAll();
                    else
                        App.Current.MainPage.DisplayAlert("", "Password must be same as above!", "OK");

                });
            }
        }

        private async void RegisterAll()
        {
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(Email) || string.IsNullOrEmpty(Password))
                await App.Current.MainPage.DisplayAlert("Empty Values", "Please enter Email and Password", "OK");
            else
            {

                if (isProvider)
                    userType = "Proveedor";


                else
                    userType = "Cliente";
                //Instantiate Usuario
                Usuario user = new Usuario(email, password, isProvider, ContactName, CelularNumber, CelularCompany, userType);

        
               

                if (user != null)
                {

                    // Register Usuario y Proveedor
                    if(user.TipoUsuario == "Proveedor")
                    {
                        //Create[Post] user in cloud.
                        await _userService.CreateUser(user);

                        //Instantiate Proveedor
                        Proveedor proveedor = new Proveedor(idProveedor, razonSocial, domicilioFiscal, cuit);

                        //Create[Post] proveedor in cloud.
                        await _userService.CreateProvider(proveedor);

                        await App.Current.MainPage.DisplayAlert("Proveedor Registrado Exitosamente!", "", "Ok");

                        await App.Current.MainPage.Navigation.PushAsync(new AppointmentsAdminStorePage());

                    }
                    else // Register Usuario Cliente
                    {

                        await _userService.CreateUser(user);

                        await App.Current.MainPage.DisplayAlert("Cliente Registrado Exitosamente!", "", "Ok");

                        //Navigate to MapPage after success
                        await App.Current.MainPage.Navigation.PushAsync(new MapPage());
                    }
                   
                }
                else
                {
                    await App.Current.MainPage.DisplayAlert("Error", "SignUp Fail", "OK");
                }

            }

        }
```

The images show what I want to accomplish.
Just to be able to hide/unhide and bind the bottom section of the screen as well.
Thanks for your help!
ML

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I4C5u.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7SSQN.png)

Comment: It would create the Proveedor object because it wasn't binding the Entries. It is now resolved. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try by specifying binding `Source`:

```
<StackLayout IsVisible="{Binding Source={x:Reference IsProviderSwitch}, Path=IsToggled}">
```